# Getting Malayalam font in notepad

Tags: c#-2.0, notepad

I am working in C# Windows application, i am writing some content to notepad, print.txt which is located at start up position. after writing i am sending it to printer using following code

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();  
RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, 
    Application.StartupPath + "\\print.txt");
```

But when doing so i am not able to get malayalam font in print. But malayalam getting in the note pad file and even when printing directly from note pad.
Anyone can suggest a solution
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your text is encoded in Unicode, and why on earth are you even using notepad? ANY other text-editing program on the planet would do a better job.

Comment: no issue with unicode because i am able to see it in notepad. my problem is that the malayama font is not getting printed while sending the notepad to printer using code. but malayalam is printed when i manually opens the note pad and press ctrl+P

Answer (score 1):

Text files (`.txt`) created with Notepad don't contain any font information. Notepad **displays** your text using the font you select, but the file itself doesn't contain fonts or any other formatting (bold, italic, and so forth).

You can remove Notepad from the equation, and use a `RichTextBox` instead; that file format allows embedded fonts and other information (such as tables and images). You can then send that file to the printer, and let the default `.rtf` application (WordPad or Word) to handle printing instead.

If you want to print in a specific font without using an external application, you need to either send the proper codes to your printer to set the printer's internal font, or use software that sends that information instead (like Word or PDF).

Setting your printer's internal font is vendor specific, and you'd need to check the documentation for your printer brand and model, which should be available from the printer's manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print other language like Bangla or Hindi using your code? If not then probably your C# development environment isn't utf-8 enabled.

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment.